# What is the function that does the opposite of array_pop()?

Tags: php

`array_pop()` returns the last value of an array and removes that value from the array.

What is the function that does the opposite of `array_pop()`, i.e. returns and removes the first value of an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the php manual:-

> [array_shift()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched.

I know this is a trivial question but I did a Google search for opposite of array_pop() and nothing popped up, so I thought I'd share the question on here and it might save lots of people about 4 seconds each :)

Comment: Some might say that `array_push` does the opposite of `array_pop` and that the opposite of `array_shift` is `array_unshift`.

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of opposite, I also immediately thought of array_push when I read the title of this question :)

Comment: @hakre Yeah I see what you're saying, but I imagine that anyone searching for opposite of `array_pop()` is not going to be looking for `array_push()` since they can just do `$array[] = ...` unless they have multiple values

Comment: I was just noting that in case someones googles the question. You explain your meaning of opposite, so only a comment, not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 27):

A bit more detail.

### Functionality

1. `array_pop()`**pops** an element off **end** of the array.
2. `array_push()` **pushes** an element into the **end** of the array.
3. `array_shift()` **pops** an element off the **beginning** of the array.
4. `array_unshift()` **pushes** an element into the **beginning** of the array.

### Beautiful Matrix

Here’s a beautiful matrix that shows each function in respect to the others. Notice the symbolic arrows.

> **Beginning**                        **End**
>   **Pop** from         <-`array_shift()`        `array_pop()`->
>   **Push** into        ->`array_unshift()`    `array_push()`<-

It was *real* uneasy to create it with SO’s markup restrictions. Click on edit to check out the source (and of course feel free to enhance it)!

### Shift VS. Unshift confusion

So. When trying to memorize all 4 functions, it was very easy for me to learn what `array_pop()` does: *it just pops an element off the end of array*. Naturally, the functionality of the complementary `array_push()` was absolutely clear from the first shot too: *it pushes an element back into the end*. However, the two opposite brothers `array_shift()` and `array_unshift()` kept giving me hard time when I was trying to remember which one *pops* and which one *pushes*. :-/ I had to constantly look it up.

Funny, the solution I came up with was simply the **letter “U”**. Those that have it: `array_pUsh()` and `array_Unshift()` - pUsh. The other two - pop. Easy-peasy!

Hope this helps anyone!